# jQueryUI Accordion: how to open it above existing content (not to move that content down)?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

Is it possible through it's options set such behaviour to the [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-clearStyle)?

I mean like "Theme switcher" on their site. When it opens, examples menu doesn't move down and it's like imposed on this menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [documentation for the accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/). On the first page, there's a line that states:

> **NOTE: If you want multiple sections open at once, don't use an
>   accordion**

The documentation then proceeds to provide a simple way to achieve multiple panels open at once:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.accordion .head').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        return false;
    }).next().hide();
});
```

Combine that with some simple markup and styling, and you're in business.

[**Here's a working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/Uc38T/).